# Can't Pass Resized QLabel Geometry From Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pyqt, pyqt5

I’m using PyQt5 and OpenCV.  I want to create a class that reads a frame of the video and performs a rubber band stretch to generate the geometry that will be used in by a different class to crop the video stream (this second class is not included in this example).

In this example, an image is captured from a webcam stream, then displayed.  A rubber band stretch over the image generates a geometry that is printed.  The geometry prints without issue within the `ReGeomVid` class, but not within `main()`.  I need to get the geometry into `main()`. Help is appreciated.

```
import sys, cv2
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QRubberBand, QApplication, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QSize

class ReGeomVid (QLabel):
    def __init__(self, cap, parent=None):
        super(ReGeomVid, self).__init__(parent)
        self.cap = cap
        self.currentQRect = QRect()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI (self):        
        ret, frame = self.cap.read() #First frame read is black
        ret, frame = self.cap.read() #Second frame read is normal
        if ret == True:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img = QImage(frame,frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
            pix = QPixmap.fromImage(img)
            self.setPixmap(QPixmap(pix))

    def mousePressEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        self.originQPoint = eventQMouseEvent.pos()
        print(self.originQPoint)
        self.currentQRubberBand = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self.currentQRubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.originQPoint, QSize()))
        self.currentQRubberBand.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        self.currentQRubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.originQPoint, eventQMouseEvent.pos()).normalized())

    def mouseReleaseEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        self.currentQRubberBand.hide()
        self.currentQRect = self.currentQRubberBand.geometry()        
        self.currentQRubberBand.deleteLater()
        self.croppedPixmap = self.pixmap().copy(self.currentQRect)
        print("In mouserelease: Geometry = ", self.currentQRect)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myQApplication = QApplication(sys.argv)
    stream = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    x = ReGeomVid(stream)
    x.show()
    pixMainGeom = x.currentQRect
    print("In main: Geometry = ", x.currentQRect)
    sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `self.currentQRect` is set in `mouseReleaseEvent`. So, when the *print* in your main is executed, it's still invalid.

Use a signal to run the code in your main when the `self.currentQRect` is ready:

```
class ReGeomVid (QLabel):
    currentQRectChanged = pyqtSignal(QRect)
...
    def mouseReleaseEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        ...
        self.currentQRectChanged.emit(self.currentQRect)

def printCurrentQRect(rect):
    print("In main: Geometry = ", rect)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myQApplication = QApplication(sys.argv)
    stream = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    x = ReGeomVid(stream)
    x.show()
    x.currentQRectChanged.connect(printCurrentQRect)
    sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

Comment: Works perfectly!